# How to Change BackgroundColor of DatePicker's inner Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

What I want to do is to change the `Background` from the `TextBox` that is inside the `DatePicker`.

I tried to get it work by adding the `<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}"` but had no success because I already  have other `<Style>` there.

Here is my `<DatePicker>`:

```
                    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinHeight="20">
                       <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
                            <Binding Path="ViewModel.Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                        </DatePicker.SelectedDate>

                        <DatePicker.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                        Path=ViewModel.IsDirty}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                        Path=ViewModel.IsInvalid}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DatePicker.Style>
                    </DatePicker>
```

So when the `IsDirty` is triggered the `Background`gets `LightYellow` but the inner `TextBox` `Background` is still `White`.

How do I change this `Background` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your own custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<DatePicker>
    <DatePicker.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                    <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" 
                                               Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" 
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                               Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <DatePickerTextBox.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                        <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </DatePickerTextBox.Template>
                    </DatePickerTextBox>
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                             Path=ViewModel.IsDirty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                             Path=ViewModel.IsInvalid}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DatePicker.Template>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: can you tell me where I can set the `CornerRadius` and `Height` from the `DatePickerTextBox` please? I already set `CornerRadius` from `PART_Root` but it seems that the `DatePickerTextBox` somehow overlays the corners. Furthermore  I changed the `Icon` and unfortunately my `Icon` is smaller than the original, so a little difference in height can be seen between `DatePickerTextBox` and `Icon`. - Thank you

Answer (score 4):

In your `Style`, just add the desired `DatePickerTextBox` style as a resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- your triggers here -->
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: thank you that worked for me. now I want to change the `DatePickerTextBox` border color when `MouseOver` is `true`. I tried it by adding `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>` to the `<Style.Resources>` but it doesn't work. Have you any hint for me?

Comment: You should ask another question, because the use case you describe is a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background regularly, and set style to the DatePicker, and set it property such `<LinearGradientBrush>` or `<SolidColorBrush>`

(improvement on the answer of dymanoid)

```
<DatePicker FontSize="22" 
            Text="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Margin="5 0">
            <DatePicker.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.35"/>
            </DatePicker.Background>
            <DatePicker.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
           </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
```